# Performance Tuning Linux

Tags: linux, performance, linux-networking, hard-drive, latency

Performance Tuning/ Monitoring/Latency keeping in mind I see following 4 items & in each item they are lot of tools.

1. CPU
2. Memory
3. IO
4. Network

What I see following tools we do use.

- vmstat
- mpstat
- sar
- iostat
- netstat
- dstat
- iptraf
- netperf
- ethtool
- iperf
- tcptrace
- numa
- tuned
- PCP (Performance Co-Pilot)
- iotop
- htop
- top
- iftop
- ifstat
- strace
- perf
- top
- dtrace
- stap
- iostat
- iotop
- blktrace
- pidstat
- mpstat
- dstat
- free
- tcpdump
- ip
- nicstat
- ping
- ethtool

If any thing I am missing request you add.

Q1. Recommend tools ? & Best practices/results.
Q2. To getting best results out of X86 server with Linux(Fedora/CentOS/Ubuntu) what are tools to use and why?

Using all of your experience want create one Live CD out these tools.

I don't know serverfault admin will allow such question. Thank in advance to all Guru's out there.

Comment: you are missing https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add some tool to helps for get accurate result

```
 1.Lsof
 2.Psacct or Acct – Monitor User Activity
 3.Monit – Linux Process and Services Monitoring
 4.NetHogs
 5.Monitorix – System and Network Monitoring
 6.Arpwatch – Ethernet Activity Monitor
 7.Suricata – Network Security Monitoring
 8.VnStat PHP – Monitoring Network Bandwidth
 9.Nagios – Network/Server Monitoring
 10.Nmon: Monitor Linux Performance
 11.Collectl: All-in-One Performance Monitoring Tool.
```

Answer (score 7):

[Brandan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) has made a number of visual diagrams of which tool to use on what part of your system that make really nice cheat sheets:

## Tools:

[image: Performance Observability]

## Which options to use in `sar` to monitor:

[image]

## And closely related:

[image: Linux Benchmarking Tools]

## Translate observations into tuning with:

[image]